# Why are no documents returned with this NEST wildcard search with C#/ElasticSearch?

Tags: c#, nest

This NEST wildcard search is returning zero (0) documents, even though it should because there is data in my index that has this criteria. It is a valid connection and there are no errors showing when setting breakpoints. Any Ideas?

```
public class Book_ES
{

    public string book_title { get; set; }
     public string book_author { get; set; }
}

 sr_detailed = new SearchDescriptor<Book_ES>()


                    .Index("books_3").Take(10000)
                   .Query(a => a
                          .Bool(b => b
                            .Should(c => c
                              .Wildcard(d => d
                                
 .Field(f=>f.book_title).Field(g=>g.book_author).Value("A*")
                              )
                            )
                          )
                        
                    ).Highlight(h => h.Fields(f => f.Field("*").PreTags("<span class='hit' style='background-color:yellow'>").PostTags("</span>")))
                   ;

 var results = Esclient.Search<Book_ES>(sr_detailed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share your mapping but I assume it looks like

```
{
  "books_3": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "book_title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "book_author": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in this case, when you put `A*` as a value for your wildcard query you won't get any results back because both `book_title` and `book_author` use standard analyzer for the text field and all uppercased characters are removed from indexed tokens - for this configuration elasticsearch won't store any tokens starting with `A`, see below

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "Test"
}

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You can set `case_insensitive` to `true` in your wildcard query and that will fix your issue as [docs say](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

> case_insensitive [7.10.0]Added in 7.10.0. (Optional, Boolean) Allows
> case insensitive matching of the pattern with the indexed field values
> when set to true. Default is false which means the case sensitivity of
> matching depends on the underlying field’s mapping.